# Can CHECK constraint be used to prevent re-assignment of a column value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a nullable column that should be only assignable once. Once set, any attempt to overwrite the value should fail. Can this be accomplished with a CHECK constraint (i.e. is it possible to look at pre-update value of the column and compare with the new value) or can this only be accomplished with an UPDATE TRIGGER?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `update` trigger, with a query like this:

```
update t1 set
    field = d.field
from
    table t1
    inner join inserted i on
        t1.id = i.id
    inner join deleted d on
        t1.id = d.id
where
    i.field != d.field
```

A check constraint has no temporal recognition, that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

No, Check constraints cannot see the "before" value of a column.

You would need a trigger for this or manage it through permissions (e.g. only allow update permissions on a View that does not contain the column).

See also related Connect Item [Add DRI to enforce immutable column values](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/346200/add-dri-to-enforce-immutable-column-values)